# How to Achive And Condition in IN OPERATOR

Tags: mysql

> IN operator apply or condition between values in IN(). I want
>   to achieve and condition between values in array. How can it be done?

```
SELECT J.ID , J.U_POST_ID,
        J.TITLE,J.CREATION_DATE,J.STATUS,
        R.FIRST_NAME, R.LAST_NAME,R.CLINICAL_CLINIC_NAME,
        J.REQUIREMENT,J.STATE,J.CITY,J.DESCRIPTION,J.CALL_DUR,J.USER_ID
        FROM  
        df_job_meta M LEFT OUTER JOIN df_job_post J ON
        M.JOB_ID = J.ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN df_register_users R ON 
        R.ID = J.USER_ID
        WHERE
        J.STATUS='ACTIVE'  AND R.OCCUPATION !='student' AND J.STATE IN ('Maharashtra') AND J.CITY IN ('Nagpur') and  M.VALUE IN ('Clinical','Fresher','BDS Intern','Full Time')
```

> Above query select  VALUE of "fresher" or "Clinical"

```
I want to  select row  associated with both  fresher and Clinical
```

**TABLE STRUCTURE IS AS BELOW**

```
META_KEY   |    VALUE
```

---

```
experience |    fresher
num_vacancy|    1
profile    |Clinical
```

Comment: what's wrong with using and instead of in clause?

Comment: How many cities do you want to include in the query?

Comment: i am in sitiation where i want to choose record from mysql with both values in array

Comment: So you may have a customer which can co-exits in both Paris and London ?

Comment: But how can a field contain two values at once? This: `SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE City="London" AND City="Paris";` will always return an empty set.

Comment: I don't see how that "table structure" is of any use, it doesn't have anything to do with cities

Comment: `TABLE STRUCTURE IS AS BELOW` .. which table is it?

Comment: it was  for  example

Answer (score 0):

You can use **IN** clause to replace many **OR** conditions. Otherwise just use AND.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain it would work, but I figure it should

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
    WHERE `VALUE` REGEXP 'fresher|Clinical'
```

Comment: Are your search values in an array or are is it the data stored that is in a array?

Comment: This is also an `OR`.

Comment: Yes my values are in array

Comment: And how are you building your query? It's incredible hard to help you with the limited amount of information

Comment: IN ('Clinical','Fresher','BDS Intern','Full Time') <- Where are they coming from? Are they static like that or do you use some other code to write them in?